# Python equivilent to R's str()?

Tags: python

In R you can run `str()` on an object and it will print out the details of where various slots in the object are stored and how to access them.  Sometimes in R you may call something with the `@` or the `$` symbol, you can also access it with a an index call like so `object[[1]][[1]]`  etc etc...

documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/str

Is there any function like `str()` for python?  That will generally allow you to see all the datastructures associated with a particular instance of a class and how to access them?  I think classes in python are less restrictive than in R so this may not be possible.

Comment: There is no such method, largely for the reasons you already mentioned, though `vars` and `dir` may help.